# Preserving white space through XML/XSLT processing chain

Tags: xml, xslt, whitespace

1. User types text into a multi-line text box in the browser
2. Data is stored as part of an XML snippet in a  SQL Server xml column
3. XML snippet is later incorporated into a larger xml document
4. Document is processed via XSLT into an HTML email
5. Recipient is expected to see the original line breaks

I tried:

- CDATA (removed by SQL)
- `<PRE>` tag in the output around the comments and encoding of the NL character
- encoded `<BR>` tag in the data (does not get decoded in the HTML)

Can this be done without rearchitecting everything?

Per request in the comments, here is the actual code:

### The XSL

```
<TD>
    <xsl:value-of select="//MemoComment"/>
</TD>
```

### Variations of input data into the XSLT

1. `<MemoComment>Previous job: Associate, Boston<br/>Test1<br/>Test2</MemoComment>`
2. `<MemoComment>Previous job: Associate, Boston &amp;#xA;Test1 &amp;#xA;Test2</MemoComment>`
3. `<MemoComment>Previous job: Associate, Boston&amp;lt;br/&amp;gt;Test1&lt;br/&gt;Test2</MemoComment>`

### Corresponding XSLT Results

1. `<TD>Previous job: Associate, BostonTest1Test2</TD>`
2. `<TD>Previous job: Associate, Boston&amp;#xA;Test1&amp;#xA;Test2</TD>`
3. `<TD>Previous job: Associate, Boston&amp;lt;br/&amp;gt;Test1&lt;br/&gt;Test2</TD>`

None of which renders correctly in Outlook.

Comment: I'm not sure how SQL server processes XML data, but if before transforming with XSLT you have preserved white spaces in the XML file, you can preserve them in the stylesheet as well.

Comment: 4) Document is processed via XSLT into an HTML email 5) Recipient is expected to see the original line breaks. So is your end result a HTML with line break characters? That won't work, because HTML collapses whitespace and line break characters get converted to spaces.

Comment: Jasso, I tried wrapping the output in PRE tags which would preserve any whitespace

Comment: @khachik, the whitespace is lost in the XML processing, before the XSLT even gets to look at it

Comment: @cdonner, at what point is the whitespace lost? Also, if the `<br>` tags are not getting turned into actual line breaks, I would suspect the XSLT is escaping them; you would need to show us the relevant part of your XSLT and a sample of its output to know for sure.

Comment: P.S. CDATA is just "lexical sugar". It's not surprising that it has no downstream effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason for your problem was that you used `<xsl:value-of>`

```
<TD>
    <xsl:value-of select="//MemoComment"/>
</TD>
```

when you actually needed `<xsl:copy-of>`

```
<TD>
    <xsl:copy-of select="//MemoComment/node()"/>
</TD>
```

`<xsl:value-of>` only selects the string value of the selected node. What you actually wanted is to copy of whole node including the elements that it contained. Then you can save the data as a formatted XHTML snippet without the need of element syntax escaping (format number 1 on your input list).

Usage of `disabe-output-escaping="yes"` is often discouraged because it can lead to outputting malformed XML. Also all XSLT processors don't implement this feature since it actually takes effect only when the document is serialized, and might not have any effect if the output document is passed on from the processor as a data structure.

Comment: Thanks, jasso - I just found this out myself, and copy-of works fine, with the embedded tags stored unescaped.

Answer (score 1):

Try embedding escaped `<br>` elements in your text and setting the `disable-output-escaping` attribute of your [`<xsl:value-of>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256181.aspx) element to `yes`:

```
<MemoComment>Previous job: Associate, Boston&lt;br/&gt;Test1&lt;br/&gt;Test2</MemoComment>

<xsl:value-of select="//MemoComment" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Comment: So actually, it is not quite working yet. It took care of the output side only. When I manually placed the escaped <br> element as you suggested into the XML document for the transformation, the result was good. But when I put it in the database programmatically, the ampersand is escaped as well, resulting in &amp;lt; etc which does not get unescaped correctly. Do you have any additional insights?

Comment: It all depends on whichever step in the pipeline is actually encoding the ampersand characters. Are these already escaped in your database? If not, your data access layer probably encodes them when building the XML document that gets translated, you should look into that.

Comment: Yes, they are escaped in the database.

Comment: @cdonner, in that case, you can try storing the "raw" data from your `<textarea>` element in the database. Line feeds will probably be stored as `\r\n` sequences, you can then have your DAL replace these sequences with escaped `<br>` elements.

Comment: Frédéric, that's exactly what I was doing, but like I said, the ampersand in the escaped BR tags got escaped again, and when they were unescaped at the tail end, they were restored to the actual tag (not escaped at all), which did not work. In other words:
&lt; became &amp;lt; became < (as opposed to &lt; again).